# Three and Tween.js - unwanted spinning, is this gimbal lock?

Tags: three.js, tween.js

I'm tweening an Object from here

```
Position (X:82.22, Y:-8.31, Z:57.75)
Rotation (X:-3.00, Y:-0.95, Z:-3.02)
```

to here

```
Position (X:57.36, Y:-8.31, Z:93.78)
Rotation (X:-3.05, Y:-0.55, Z:-3.10)
```

with this tween

```
            behaviour.tween = new TWEEN.Tween(behaviour.origin).to(behaviour.target,behaviour.offsetTime * 1000)
            .onUpdate(function(){

                hotspot.position.x = behaviour.origin.pX;
                hotspot.position.y = behaviour.origin.pY;
                hotspot.position.z = behaviour.origin.pZ;
                hotspot.rotation.x = behaviour.origin.rX;
                hotspot.rotation.y = behaviour.origin.rY;
                hotspot.rotation.z = behaviour.origin.rZ;
                hotspot.scale.set(behaviour.origin.scale,behaviour.origin.scale,behaviour.origin.scale);
                hotspot.opacity = behaviour.origin.opacity;

            }).
```

And the object spins along the z axis as it moves across the scene.

Is this likely to be Gimbal lock? If so, what's the way to get around this?

Comment: look into SLERP with quaternions

Comment: it looks like on the y-axis you are rotating from roughly -pi/3 to -pi/6. It shouldn't be gimbal lock. try having one positional tween and one rotational tween executed at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always safer to use Quaternion for transitions. For me it works very well without using `slerp`, but just using Tween.js.

```js
// excerpt from my code
var q = obj.quaternion.clone().multiply(new THREE.Quaternion().setFromAxisAngle(new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), theta));

new TWEEN.Tween(obj.quaternion)
  .to(q, time)
  .onUpdate(function () { object.quaternion.copy(this); }) // onUpdate isn't really needed in this case
  .start();
```

So, for you, it should work with something like this:

```js
behaviour.origin.position = new THREE.Vector3(82.22, -8.31, 57.75);
behaviour.origin.quaternion = ew THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(-3.00, -0.95, 3.02));

behaviour.target.position = new THREE.Vector(57.36, -8.31, 93.78);
behaviour.target.quaternion = ew THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(3.05, -0.55, 3.10));

new TWEEN.Tween(behaviour.origin)
  .to(behaviour.target, behaviour.offsetTime * 1000)
  .onUpdate(function () {
    hotspot.position.copy(behaviour.origin.position);
    hotspot.quaternion.copy(behaviour.origin.quaternion);
  })
  .start();
```

---

**UPDATE:** Ok, it is adviced to use quaternion `slerp()`, otherwise it can result strange behaviours, too. Hence, I suppose, the code should look like this:

```
behaviour.origin.position = new THREE.Vector3(82.22, -8.31, 57.75);
behaviour.origin.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(-3.00, -0.95, 3.02));

behaviour.target.position = new THREE.Vector(57.36, -8.31, 93.78);
behaviour.target.quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(new THREE.Euler(3.05, -0.55, 3.10));

behaviour.origin.t = 0;
behaviour.target.t = 1;

new TWEEN.Tween(behaviour.origin)
  .to(behaviour.target, behaviour.offsetTime * 1000)
  .onUpdate(function () {
    hotspot.position.copy(behaviour.origin.position);
    THREE.Quaternion.slerp(behaviour.origin.quaternion, behaviour.target.quaternion, hotspot.quaternion, behaviour.origin.t);
  })
  .start();
```

Comment: Quaternions that represent rotations must have unit length. Tweening as you have implemented it does not guarantee the intermediate values have unit length. You should use `slerp()`.

Comment: Ok, good to know. I guess, it worked for me, because I only made transitions around one axis, and the objects themelves were only repositioned, but not rotated.